# How to route URL pattern with URL path separator?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have to route the following URL pattern to view `api/v1/{resourceId}/owners` in DRF

But the problem is `resourceID` contains `/` in it. eg `api/v1/somethings/value/owners` the additional `/` causing get 404 resource not found exception

Is there way to route the URL and get `resourceID` in view

My urls.py

```
path('api/v1/<str:resource_id>/owners', ResourceOwnershipView.as_view())
```

views.py

```
class ResourceOwnershipView(APIView):

    def get(self, request: HttpRequest, resource_id: str) -> Response:
        # do something with resourceID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<str:>` probably doesn't allow slashes in it. I would try to use regular expression version of routing definition `re_path`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#re-path